# Xamarin Forms Control Not Shown When ItemSource is Initialling Empty

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I have the following XAML in my Page:

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="20, 5, 10, 5"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   TextColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                   FontSize="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextSize, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Text="{Binding [bank_details__frequency], Source={x:Static i18n:Translator.Instance}}" />

            <Picker Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Title="{Binding [single_line_miscellaneous__select], Source={x:Static i18n:Translator.Instance}}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DonationFrequencies}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDonationFrequency, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    TextColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                    FontSize="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextSize, Mode=OneWay}"
                    WidthRequest="200"/>

            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="20, 0, 0, 0"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                   LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                   TextColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                   FontSize="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextSize, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Text="{Binding [bank_details__donation_amount], Source={x:Static i18n:Translator.Instance}}" />

            <Picker Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Title="{Binding [single_line_miscellaneous__select], Source={x:Static i18n:Translator.Instance}}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DonationAmounts}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDonationAmount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    TextColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                    FontSize="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextSize, Mode=OneWay}"
                    WidthRequest="200"/>

            <Entry Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="2" 
                   Margin="0, 5, 0, 5"
                   FontSize="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextSize, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Placeholder="{Binding [single_line_miscellaneous__other], Source={x:Static i18n:Translator.Instance}}"
                   HeightRequest="{StaticResource FundraisingEntryHeight}"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.InputBackgroundColour, Mode=OneWay}"
                   TextColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.InputTextColour, Mode=OneWay}"
                   PlaceholderColor="{Binding Campaign.CampaignProfile.PlaceholderTextColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Keyboard="Numeric"
                   Text="{Binding Current.EntryDonationAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" />


            <control:CheckBoxViewList Grid.Row="2"
                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                                      Margin="20"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding PaymentTypes, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedPaymentType, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Initially when my Page loads, the PaymentTypes (ObservableCollection) is empty and nothing is displayed in my CheckBoxViewList.  Once SelectedDonationFrequency has a value, the contents of PaymentTypes are updated, however the UI doesn't show anything.  However if I tap into the Entry control and then dismiss the keyboard, my control shows as expected.  Initially I thought I could just set a default value for the CheckBoxViewList, however if I update SelectedDonationFrequency, which causes PaymentTypes to be updated, the control disappears from the UI until I tap the Entry control and then dismiss the keyboard.  Once I do this I can update SelectedDonationFrequency and see the new values in my CheckBoxViewList.

I then thought calling ForceLayout would solve the problem, however that had no effect.  I added this code after the PaymentTypes collection was updated:

```
this.carouselPage.ForceLayout()
this.carouselPage.Focus();
```

However it had no effect.  I've also tried setting the height of the Row to 200 (random value), however that didn't work either.

I have the same issue with a number of controls, including Grid, so it's nothing to do with the CheckBoxViewList control.  This also only happens on Android.

Has anyone experienced this or similar?

Update:

PaymentTypes is an IEnumable.  BuildDonationPaymentTypes:

```
private void BuildDonationPaymentTypes(string donorPaymentType = null)
{
    DonationFrequencyConfig donationFrequencyConfig = Campaign?.CampaignProfile?.DonationFrequencyConfig.Where(a => a.Identifier.Equals(Current?.EntryDonationFrequency)).SingleOrDefault();

    if (donationFrequencyConfig == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    PaymentTypes = new ObservableCollection<Checkbox>();

    foreach (IdentifierPair paymentType in donationFrequencyConfig?.PaymentTypes)
    {
        string displayText = Translator.Instance[paymentType.Identifier].ToString();

        PaymentTypes.Add(new Checkbox()
        {
            Text = displayText,
            Value = paymentType.Identifier,
            Checked = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(donorPaymentType) && displayText.Equals(donorPaymentType, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)),
            TextColour = Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextColor,
            CheckColour = Campaign.CampaignProfile.PlaceholderTextColor,
            TextSize = Campaign.CampaignProfile.TextSize,
            CheckSize = Campaign.CampaignProfile.CheckSize
        });
    }

    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PaymentTypes));
}
```

IdentifierPair is just a name/value pair - both are string's

Another Update:

We I remove the ScrollView and StackLayout - the UI updates correctly

Comment: Try updating your itemssource in an overridden OnAppearing method of your view.

Also, does the model class in your observablecollection implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: The checkboxlist is based on https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/alexdunn.org/2018/04/10/xamarin-tip-build-your-own-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms/amp/. I hit breakpoints when the collection changes.  I also experience the same problem when toggling the IsVisible property of the Grid control.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give more insight into the model class you are binding to that view.

Comment: I've updated the question with Model details

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code logic to following:

```
var tmp = new ObservableCollection<Checkbox>();
... add new items to tmp
PaymentTypes.Clear();
PaymentTypes.AddRange(tmp);
```

Comment: Thanks, however the UI still doesn't show anything until I tap into the Entry